# Nodejs file upload using HTTP post

Tags: node.js, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm extending a Cypress Testing plugin for TestRail that pushes Cypress test results to TestRail. The plugin adds only test results (Pass/Fail) and I'm trying to upload screenshots taken duing the test. I am able to use the API to read and write other information using GET and POST calls, but I'm unable to get the file upload to work.

Here is the documentation of the API call I'm trying to implement:
[TestRAil File upload](https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077039051284-Accessing-the-TestRail-API#example-attachment-upload-0-3)

I got the API to work using Python:

```
resp = R.post('https://example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_attachment_to_result/123456',auth=self.credentials, files={'attachment': open('/home/user/path/to/file.png', 'rb')})
```

When I tried this in Javascript (Nodejs):

```
const got = require('got')
const fs = require('fs')

file = ‘/home/user/path/to/file.png’
const form = new FormData()

form.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream(file)) // Option A
form.append('attachment', fs.readFileSync(file)) // Option B

const response = await got('https://example.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/add_attachment_to_result/123456', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    authorization,
  },
  body: form
})
```

I get the same errors for both options A & B:

```
RequestError: The `body` option must be a stream.Readable, string or Buffer
```

What is the correct way to prepare a file for uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your file path it's not Imported correctly use path module given by nodejs and try console log before post request

```
    const path=require('path');
    file = path.join(__dirname,‘/home/user/path/to/file.png’);
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('attachment', fs.createReadStream(file)) // Option A
    form.append('attachment', fs.readFileSync(file)) // Option B
    console.log("file is loaded",form);
```

I have Tried it out myself working fine

```
    import got from "got";
    import fs from "fs";
    const filePath = "./icon.png";

    const fetchResponse = async () => {
    try {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append("attachment", fs.createReadStream(filePath)); // Option A
        form.append("attachment", fs.readFileSync(filePath)); // Option B
        console.log(form);
        const response = await got(
        "https://webhook.site/8c554904-0716-4408-b48b-35fcc0bf65ce",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
            body: form,
        },
        );
        console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Errror in Fetch", err);
    }
    };

    fetchResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Saurabh, but it does not make the file upload work. I was already using the absolute filepath. file = path.join(__dirname,‘/home/user/path/to/file.png’) file is now: /home/user/myproject/nodejs/home/user/path/to/file.png which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file using Node.js, you can use the **form-data** module to create a readable stream for the file. Here's how:

1-> Install **form-data** module: **npm install form-data**.
2-> Use **FormData** to create a form and append the file with **fs.createReadStream(file)**
3-> Set headers including **'Content-Type':** **'multipart/form-data'**.
4-> Send the request with **got** or any HTTP library.
Ensure to replace placeholders like **file** and **YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER** with actual values.